# flask_app command does not found packages

Tags: flask

Currently referring to this tutorial.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/

The directory folder is as below.

[image]

**init**.py ->

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

problem:
[image]

try:

1. create app.py and run
   --> success

   [image]
   [image]

Question.

Why FLASK_APP can't recognize flask package?
What should I do?

Comment: I tried but it still prints the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're launching from powershell, and haven't used the powershell launch instructions from the tutorial page you linked:

```
> $env:FLASK_APP = "flaskr"
> $env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
> flask run
```